# Some questions about thick sets and syndetic sets

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

A syndetic set $S$ is a subset of the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ or integers $\mathbb{Z}$, having the property of "bounded gaps": that the sizes of the gaps in the sequence of natural numbers is bounded. That is to say, $S$ is a syndetic set, if there exist a positive integer $l$, such that for any $n$ , we have $\{n,n+1,\cdots, n+l\}\cap S$ is non-empty.

A thick set $T$ is a subset of the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ or integers $\mathbb{Z}$ that contains arbitrarily long intervals. That is, given a thick set $T$, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exist $a_n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\{a_n,a_n+1,\cdots,a_n+n\}\subseteq T$.

A subset of $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ is piecewise syndetic if it is the intersection of a thick set with a syndetic set.

My questions as follows,

1. A set $P$ is piecewise syndetic iff for some fixed $l$, $P$ contains arbitarily long strings $a_1<a_2\cdots<a_n$ satisfying $a_{i+1}-a_i\leq l$.
2. If $T$ is a thick subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $x\in T$, then $T\backslash\{x\}$ is a thick subset, too.
3. Does there exist abstract/general definition about thick/piecewise syndetic set of a topological (semi)group $G$?

How to prove them or explain them?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with $2$.
Fix the size of the interval you want to find in $T\setminus\left\{x\right\}$ to be $n$, find a subinterval of $T$ of length $2n+1$, so it's easily follows that you have an interval of length at-least $n$ in $T\setminus\left\{x\right\}$.

For $3$,there are general definitions, probably they appear in Furstenberg's book. In the current terminology of Tao and Hrushovski, they probably contain words like "approximate subgroups" and things like "approximate lattices".

For $1$, the direct from left to right is clear, given such interval in a thick set, you can "sieve" it out along the syndethic subset.
For the other way around.
Look at the set of such strings for given $\ell$, define $T$ to be the union of the intervals $[a_{1},a_{n}]$, so such set is thick by definition.
Define $S$ to be the set of sieved out numbers between such strings $[a_{1},a_{n}]$, and between such intervals, pick all the numbers in $\mathbb{N}$. So $S$ is syndetic with constant $\leq \ell$.
Hence $P$ contains the intersection of $T$ and $S$, so it contains a PS set and hence PS itself.